# Syntax Error (Missing operator) in query expression '[ProductName] = Product1' when opening a form from a search report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am building a simple database and I want to have a report open when a result from a search report is clicked on.

The VBA code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Product_name_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "Product Table", acViewReport, , "[ProductName]= " & Me![ProductName]

DoCmd.Close acReport, "KeywordSearchReport", acSaveNo

End Sub
```

I get the error message in the title. It is correctly getting the value for Me![ProductName] and [ProductName] is a field in the underlying table. I have more or less this same code for opening a report after submitting a form and it works fine.

Comment: `"[ProductName]= '" & Me![ProductName] & "'"`

Comment: Ah, that worked. Simple enough. Any idea why the single quotes are necessary in this case when the same code without them worked for a different report?

Comment: It depends on the field type - if it's a string value, like names usually are, it needs to be in quotes. if it's a numeric value, quotes cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks for the help!